# How to dynamically translate the language in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am currently using getx package for translating the language. And I am translating all the text manually like this,

```
class MyTranslations extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en': {
          'title': 'Hello World %s',
        },
        'en_US': {
          'title': 'Hello World from US',
        },
        'pt': {
          'title': 'Olá de Portugal',
        },
        'pt_BR': {
          'title': 'Olá do Brasil',
        },
      };
}
```

My question is, How to translate the language dynamically? Can we do with getx package, or any package?

Answer (score 1):

You can update it like this with GetX package:

```
  RaisedButton(
            child: Text('English'),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.updateLocale(Locale('en'));
            },
          ),
```

or

```
  RaisedButton(
            child: Text('English'),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.updateLocale(Locale('pt_BR'));
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You must also add the following code to GetMaterialApp:

```dart
    GetMaterialApp(
          title: 'Nome App',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          locale: Get.deviceLocale,
          fallbackLocale: Locale('en'), // default language if it does not exist or returns invalid.
    )
```

and to change the code just call the Get.updateLocale() function;

```dart
    ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('English'),
            onPressed: () {
              Get.updateLocale(Locale('en'));
            },
          ),
```